# jQuery animate - list items with display:inline-block

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have tried to animate height of list item with jquery animate. But strange "margin" occurs on element that are not animated. If I change remove display:inline-block, and use float:left everything works fine. How can I achive that but with display:inline-block property untouched.

Here is jsbin:

[JSBin - animate display inline block](http://jsbin.com/lanuropu/1/)

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (display, inline, block) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top;`:

```
.lista li
{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[see jsBin updated](http://jsbin.com/lanuropu/4/)

`inline-block` elements are inline-level elements. So, [`vertical-align` will apply to this element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

The default value for this property is `baseline`. So, if you stretch height of one of the elements, line-height will be stretched to higher height and other lowers elements will be placed at the "base of line".

[Other ref to vertical-align property](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/)